# Создание карты с помощью сенсоров на Arduino

Tags: arduino, поиск-библиотек

Создаю робота-пылесоса, возникла идея сделать движение по ранее пройденному пути. Соответственно, чтобы сделать это, надо записывать весь маршрут в файл со всеми препятствиями и из него потом считывать данные.
Подскажите, как реализовать запись маршрута с помощью сенсоров в файл(я думал создавать `txt-файл` и в него генерировать карту с условными обозначениями, где `*` - свободное пространство, `#` - препятствие).
Может, скинете ссылку на литературу, где можно прочитать про что-то подобное.

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=2ahUKEwjqjcWTtIroAhXMlYsKHbAmAewQFjABegQIBxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mdpi.com%2F2220-9964%2F7%2F4%2F133%2Fpdf&usg=AOvVaw2Z0SpIwmWtWHCht4sHyVKK

Comment: ИМХО основная проблема здесь не в том, как хранить, а в том, как ты будешь позиционировать робота в пространстве... если по пройденному расстоянию/направлению, то это довольно не точно особенно на кустарном шасси... а простых и точных локальных систем позиционирования для закрытых помещений я не находил... и учти, что avr'а может не хватить на всё про всё... а по хранению — есть много способов простой двумерный массив один из них... есть несколько способов улучшить его для практических применений, например, разбить на блоки...

Comment: без положительной обратной связи будет тяжело, надо абсолютно точно знать местоположение, необходимы какие-то метки или датчики, достаточно распространенный способ навигации роботов в замкнутом пространстве - измерение расстояния до ближайших опорных точек(радио, ик, лазер), или бюджетный вариант - навигация по линии, на самый крайний случай можно обклеить все qr кодами :)